# css align div with a text box

Tags: html, css

How can i get the element the "keys_values" div next to the text box..i.e, all the elements inside the div should be visible next to the text box

```
<div id="edata" class="edata" >
    <input type="text" class="users_percentage" style="width:65px;" placeholder="% of users"/>
    <div class="keys_values" style="float:'left';">
        <span>
            <input type="text" class="e_keys" style="width:65px;" placeholder="key"/>
            <input type="text" class="e_values" style="width:65px;" placeholder="value"/>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is actually a closing `</div>` missing in your code.

Comment: i have corrected it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using this:

```
<div id="edata" class="edata">
    <input type="text" class="users_percentage" placeholder="% of users" />
    <div class="keys_values">
        <span>
            <input type="text" class="e_keys" placeholder="key" />
            <input type="text" class="e_values" placeholder="value" />
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.users_percentage {
    width:65px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:4px;
}
.keys_values {
    float: left;
}
.e_keys, .e_values {
    width: 65px;
}
```

Using the classes your elements already have allows you to separate the style and structure of the page.

Note: `margin-right: 4px` was only added to match the other `input`'s style. If you're using [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/) or similar then it might not be necessary.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/Fr3kD/1/

**Update:** To add extra `span` elements below each other use this HTML:

```
<div class="keys_values">
    <span>
        <input type="text" class="e_keys" placeholder="key" />
        <input type="text" class="e_values" placeholder="value" />
    </span>
    <span>
        <input type="text" class="e_keys" placeholder="key" />
        <input type="text" class="e_values" placeholder="value" />
    </span>
</div>
```

and add an extra CSS style:

```
.keys_values span{
    display: block;
}
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Fr3kD/3/

Comment: also if i add another <span> tag with same contents and align below the current span tag with same contents ..How can i do it..

Comment: After aligning with the text box i wanted to add one more span tag wi the same elements below the aligned span tag..not next to each other

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="edata" class="edata" >
  <div style="float:left; width:49%">
    <input type="text" class="users_percentage" style="width:65px;" placeholder="% of users"/>
  </div>
  <div class="keys_values" style="float:left; width:49%">
    <span>
      <input type="text" class="e_keys" style="width:65px;" placeholder="key"/>
      <input type="text" class="e_values" style="width:65px;" placeholder="value"/>
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i cannot add a div to the text box

Comment: Why not? What restricts you from doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   <div class="keys_values" style="float:'left';margin:-26px 0 0 70px">
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IyAvOso/1)